# Is it possible to find some article that comprehensively compare the syntax difference VB and C# (prefer 2010 edition)?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

If not, maybe someone could write such an article and the view count would go through the roof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely you should be comparing features rather than syntax differences?

[VB and C# enhancements in VS 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/somasegar/vb-and-c-enhancements-in-vs-2010)

Here's the old guide: [Differences Between Visual Basic .NET and Visual C# .NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20150215155806/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/308470)

Might be of interest:

- [Switching from VB.NET to C# - any advice for learning C#?](https://web.archive.org/web/20090414042838/http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions/421373/switching-from-vb-net-to-c-any-advice-for-learning-c)
- [C# and VB.NET Comparison Cheat Sheet](http://aspalliance.com/625)
- [VB.NET and C# Comparison](https://sites.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the info. But as someone who is trying to learn/switch to VB or C# for the first time, it would be really helpful to have a list of syntax differences to refer to. I could not find a comprehensive and up to date comparison on Google. Guess I'm gonna have to write one myself and I'm sure the view count can earn me some ad revenue